# How to display image related to an array element whenever the element is mouseovered

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I have an arrays of strings (warmUpAll, legsAll) . Then I have a function that randomly picks up few of them (getRandom) and displays them. 
I want to display an image somewhere in DOM when the randomly picked elements are mouseovered/clicked. Do you think this could be possible? Should this be added in getRandom function or somewhere else?

here's my getRandom function:

```
function getRandom(arr, n) {
    var result = new Array(n),
        len = arr.length,
        taken = new Array(len);
    if (n > len)
        throw new RangeError("getRandom: more elements taken than available");
    while (n--) {
        var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * len);
        result[n] = arr[x in taken ? taken[x] : x];
        taken[x] = --len in taken ? taken[len] : len;
    }
    if (arr == warmUpAll) {
      document.getElementById("warmup").innerHTML = '<span class="exerciseheader">Warm Up - 10 minutes</span>' + "</br>" + result.join(" ");
    }
    else if (arr == legsAll){
      document.getElementById("legsDisplay").innerHTML = '<span class="exerciseheader">Legs</span>' + "</br>" + result.join(" ");
    }
    }
  }
```

HTML part of this:

```
<body>
<div id="warmup"></div>
<div id="legsDisplay"></div>
</body>
```

Thank you guys in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can write another function for hover or click ex:

```
function mouseHover()
{
//do something
}
```

and add it in your function

```
function getRandom(arr, n) {
   //...

    if (arr == warmUpAll) {
      document.getElementById("warmup").innerHTML = '<span class="exerciseheader" onmouseover="mouseHover()">Warm Up - 10 minutes</span>' + "</br>" + result.join(" ");
    }
    else if (arr == legsAll){
      document.getElementById("legsDisplay").innerHTML = '<span class="exerciseheader" onmouseover="mouseHover()">Legs</span>' + "</br>" + result.join(" ");
    }
    }
  }
```

Comment: sure, but I was hoping for some more specifics

Comment: @nosaczokowski For more specific answers, please ensure that your question is clear and specific (for eg. you didn't specified what is warmUpAll and legsAll)

Comment: @rv7, ok, I will edit. Anyways, legsAll, warmUpAll are arrays.

Comment: @nosaczokowski thanks for your cooperation and be sure to add the HTML

Comment: @rv7 basically, those two arrays shaped by get Random functionshould be placed inside body:  <div id="warmup"></div>
<div id="legsDisplay"></div>